# Simultaneous sampling of several channels with single ADC?

Tags: sampling

I am looking at [this](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7609.pdf) 8-channel, 18-bit and 200 ks/s ADC.

The datasheet claims the sampling is done simultaneously for all the channels, but the diagram shows that there is only one ADC, so how is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the T/H block in the block diagram. That's a track and hold. It holds the voltage until it is that channel's time go get the ADC.